# Dispaly nodes related to the newest taxonomy term

Tags: drupal-7

There are nodes of "product" content type which contains reference field to the "version" taxonomy terms.

User can add new term when he is creating a new node (by auto complete widget) and I need to display nodes related to the newest or "higher" term.

Is this possible without creating custom filter grammatically ?

Answer (score 1):

It is just 2 lines of code , you can place it anywhere in your page.tpl.php or 
page--front.tpl.php .

$term = max(taxonomy_get_tree(taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('version')->vid));
if ($term) 
echo l("Latest Version Products", 'taxonomy/term/'.$term->tid);

By placing the above code in your template tpl file , you can find 
"Lastest Version Product" link. and selecting that link will take user to the latest term page.

Comment: Thanks, it's good solution, but, for several reasons, I need to achieve this using views.